# How to mark the lowest value of a scatter plot with different marker size

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I created this short code last night to create a scatter plot with a colorbar. The scatter plot looks as follows:

[image]

I want to mark the smallest values of my x, y and z values with a different marker colour and size. I couldn't manage to find any useful information on how to achieve this.

```
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('YlOrRd')
x, y, z = np.loadtxt('test.txt', unpack=True) 
ms=45
pareto = plt.scatter(x,y,c=z, cmap=cm,s=ms) 
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('test')
plt.savefig('pics/test/test.png', dpi=300)
```

Comment: Does that mean mark three different ones: the one with the smallest x, the one with the smallest y, and the one with the smallest z? Or the one that's closest to (0,0,0)? Or something else?

Comment: Just plot the points manually with `plt.plot`, using the same markers as in the scatter plot, but the colour you want.

Comment: @Ardweaden I couldn't really manage that. Do you perhaps have an example?

Comment: Something like this (for minimum x): `ind = x.index(min(x))` `plt.plot(x[ind],y[ind],"ro")`

Comment: I tried to run it with the above two lines but I get this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'